# get form data on select change

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get All form data on select.when someone select country ,then collect aal form data and store in a variable,

```
  <from name="form1" id="formid">
    <input type="text" name="address">
    <input type="text" name="pincode">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="80">
     <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country">
                <option value="">Select Country</option>
                @foreach ($countries as $country) 
                    <option value="{{$country->id}}">
                    {{$country->name}}
                    </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
          </from>
```

Here Is my ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#country').change(function(){
        var cid = $(this).val();
        if(cid){
        $.ajax({
           type:"get",
           url:" {{url('/ava')}}/"+cid,
           success:function(res)
           {     
           alert(res);  
           }

        });
        }
    });
```

Here Is my controller When I am trying to send all form data

```
public function avatax(Request $request){
    $data=$request->all();
    print_r($data);
    die();
$tb = new Avalara\TransactionBuilder($client, "AGELESSZENINC", Avalara\DocumentType::C_SALESINVOICE, 'ABC');
$t = $tb->withAddress('SingleLocation', '123 Main Street',null,null, 'Irvine', $id, '92615', 'US')
    ->withLine(100.0, 1, null, "P0000000")
    ->create();
echo('<h2>Transaction #1</h2>');
echo('<pre>' . json_encode($t, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . '</pre>');
}
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Nick@I am trying to get all form  input value on select. current code is working for only  on select change and it's return only selected value, Any way I can get all form input value ,on select

Comment: And also, r u sure that your want to pass all the form data via get method? I assume, that post method would be much better solution here.

Comment: dganenco@yes I also consider for that, but first help me to get all form value

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I still don't know your problem. If you want to get all data in form and use in ajax, you can see my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#country').change(function(){
        let formData = $('#formid').serialize();
        var cid = $(this).val();
        if(cid){
        $.ajax({
           type:"get",
           url:" {{url('/ava')}}/",
           data: formData,
           success:function(res)
           {     
           alert(res);  
           }

    });
    }
});
```

You can see `serialize()` in https://api.jquery.com/serialize/. May I help you.
With post method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#country').change(function(){
        let formData = $('#formid').serialize();
        var cid = $(this).val();
        if(cid){
        $.ajaxSetup({
           headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
           }
        });
        $.ajax({
           type:"post",
           url:" {{url('/ava')}}/",
           data: formData,
           success:function(res)
           {     
           alert(res);  
           }

    });
    }
});
```

Comment: Would be nice to provide a bit more explanation here. Such as reference to official doc for `serialize` method and it's usage.

Comment: Văn Đức Nguyễn@its awesome , Please help me this with post method, rather than get, Here I do not need  +cd  with url  can i send data with url

Comment: @YadavSanjay i edit answer with post method. May I help you

Comment: Văn Đức Nguyễn@yes its correct, But ,when I am trying to alert formData value on top before ajax call,it's does not return any thing

Comment: @YadavSanjay you try using `console.log(formData)`

Comment: Văn Đức Nguyễn @its awesome, let me update my controller so hope you can crack this easily.please check update question

Comment: Văn Đức Nguyễn@can you check my update question, I am trying to send form data to my url,please check this

Comment: Văn Đức Nguyễn@please check I have added method

Comment: Văn Đức Nguyễn@    let formData = $('#formid').serialize();
        console.log(formData);    this line show me error

Comment: @YadavSanjay Your element is error. `<form></form>` not `<from></from>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203309/discussion-between-yadav-sanjay-and-vn-dc-nguyn).

Comment: Văn Đức Nguyễn@thanks, but it's showing error in ajax

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all you should use [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)() method to achieve your goal. This method will serialize your entire form and will assign it to any variable. Here my example with post method:

```js
$('#country').on('change', function() {
  const formData = $('#formid').serialize();
  console.log(formData);
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    data: formData,
    url: " {{url('/ava')}}/",
    success: function(res) {
      alert(res);
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" id="formid">
  <input type="text" name="address">
  <input type="text" name="pincode">
  <input type="hidden" name="price" value="80">
  <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="us">USA</option>
    <option value="canada">Canada</option>
    <option value="brazil">Brazil</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: dganenco@formData varible does not return any thing  when check in alert

Comment: What exactly do you get in `alert`?  A blank string?  `[Object]`?  *Never* use alert() to check the contents of anything other than a string, always use `console.log()`.  Updated the snippet to show it working fine.

Comment: Good catch, mate. I just copied it from author. Sure, that checking values via alert is bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: dganenco@this url send me lot  value in url

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $('document').ready(function(){
                alert();
                $('#country').change(function(){
                var cid = $('#country').val();
                alert(cid);
                $.ajax({
                   url: 'www.example.com/page.php',
                   method:"post",
                   data:{'country', cid},
                   success:function(res)
                   {     
                   alert(res);  
                   }

                });
                });
            });
    </script>
```

in page.php you need to get varible like this.
echo $_POST['country'];